# Strip tags does not remove/solve line breaks

Tags: php, html, tags, strip

I am having a problem with converting HTML text to plain text. Everything seems fine, but strip_tags method does not remove new lines. It looks like this:

In database:

```
<p>werasdfasdf</p>
<p>asdfasd</p>
<p>fasd</p>
<p>f</p>
<p>asdfasdf</p>
```

On site after strip tags:

```
var text2 = 'werasdfasdf
asdfasd
fasd
f
asdfasdf';
```

I would like:

```
var text2 = 'werasdfasdf asdfasd fasd f asdfasdf';
```

The problem is, that I get this error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" because of the new lines.

If it is one line, everything works fine. What should I do to remove the new lines?

Comment: Why should `strip_tags` remove line breaks? They aren't tags.

Comment: @Jay, would `trim` work here, since the new lines are within the string rather than leading/trailing? Shouldn't we just `str_replace` them instead?

Comment: Hmmmm....you're probably right @Don'tPanic

Comment: @SaTTko You can replace the line breaks with spaces: `$text2 = str_replace("\n", ' ', $text2);`

Comment: I have tried all possible things, like for example str_replace("\ ", " ", $text1); Am I doing it right?

Comment: Guess I didn't write the syntax correctly. Now, it works! Thanks @Don'tPanic !! :)